# display a string backward on the screen

Tags: c, string

Here is a small function from the book Head First on C.
This function should display a string backward on the screen.

```
void print_reverse(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    char *t = s + len - 1;
    while ( t >= s ) 
    {
         printf("%c", *t);
         t -- ;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand how it reverses 
string.

`size_t len = strlen(s);` // computes the number of 
characters in the string

`char *t = s + len - 1;` // `'t'` is a pointer to 
a type char
I don't understand what values are used for `'s'` in this equation; I've read that  when the name of an array variable is assigned to a pointer, it actually refers to the address 
of the fist character, i.e. array [0]; thus does `'s'`
have the value 0 here, or does it have the integer value
of a particular character?

For example, the word is s[] = "hello". Then if s[0] = 'h'. Adding `strlen(s)` to `s[0]` should yield 104 (in decimal), thus s + len - 1 = 104 + 6 - 1 = 109 (-1 because I assume
I have to subtract `'\0'` character that `strlen` takes
into account). But 109 is `'m'`. I don't see the way 
this equation traverses the string.

`while (t >= s)`; I assume this means that while 
`t` is not equal to zero, is it correct?

Thank you!

Comment: please read about pointers in C. Your assumption about the first character having address 0 shows that you have no idea what you are doing. Also, this program probably has undefined behavior as-is (because it decrements the pointer beyond the address of the first character.)

Answer (score 2):

First things first, `s` is a pointer and not a normal char variable. 
So, when you assign memory address of a string to `s`, it contains the address of the first location.

Pointer arithmetic: by adding 1 to a pointer, you make it point to the next memory location. Recall that strings are stored in contiguous memory locations.

So, if `s` points to "Hello",

- `printf(*s)` will print 'H'
- `printf(*(s+1))` will print 'e'.

Now, we have the length (=5) in `len`. When we add `len - 1` to `s`, we make it point 5 locations ahead. It now points to 'o'.

Then by doing `while(t >= s)` we compare two pointers (`t` and `s`) and print the value at address pointed by `t` and decrement it, till it becomes equal to `s` which is the first element.

Illustration:

Initial condition:

```
H   e   l   l   o
*s              *t
```

Now we print `*t` and decrement it.
Output: o

```
H   e   l   l   o
*s          *t
```

We continue it further:
Output: lleH

```
H   e   l   l   o
*s
*t
```

Since now `t` == `s`, we stop.

Answer (score 1):

```
void print_reverse(char *s)
```

here `s` is the pointer to the beginning of the string

```
    size_t len = strlen(s);
```

this is equals to the number of characters of the string (`\0` not counted)

```
    char *t = s + len - 1;
```

At this point, `t` is a new pointer which points at the last element of the string (read something about pointer arithmetic if this is not clear to you)

```
    while ( t >= s ) 
    {
         printf("%c", *t);
         t -- ;
    }
```

In this loop `t` gets decremented at each iteration, so that every time it points at the previous character in the string.
At the last iteration, `t==s`, which means that you are printing the first element of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It reverses the string by setting the pointer `t` to the last character of the string and then doing the following:

1. Print the character that `t` points to.
2. Decrease `t` by one (make it move one char to the left)
3. Goto (1) unless `t` now points before the first character of the string.

`s` is a pointer to the first character of the string. A string is simply a sequence of characters in memory terminated by the NUL character (`'\0'`). When `t == s`, `t` points to the first character, when `t < s`, `t` points to the first byte *before* the first character and this byte is no part of the string.

And when the loop terminates, `t` won't be zero. `t` and `s` are pointers, that means their values are memory addresses. The value of `s` is the memory address of the first character of the string and this address will certainly not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

`s` contains the address of the first character of the array, not the first character itself.  An address is not an offset from the start of the array, but an arbitrary (to the user) value.  So when you add `len - 1` to `s`, the result is a pointer to the character at index `len - 1`.

Put another way, this:

```
char *t = s + len - 1;
```

Is the same as this:

```
char *t = &s[len - 1];
```

The condition `while (t >= s)` evaluates to true as long as `t` points to a memory location at or after the start of the array.